# Finding the angle between $x-5=0$ and $2x+2y-7=0$

Tags: algebra-precalculus, trigonometry

I have 2 line equations: $x-5=0$ and $2x+2y-7=0$

I believe the angle is $45^\circ$, but I don't know how to calculate the second equation when there's a $y$ as well.

Thanks!

Comment: What do you know about straight lines?

Comment: Do you know how to find the slope of a line?

Comment: The slope of $ax+by+c=0$ is $-\frac ab$.

Comment: @DonThousand The $x-5=0$ not has the slope and it is parallel to $y$ axis. Hence I will calculate only the slope of $2x+2y-7=0$.

Comment: @Sebastiano Are you the poster of this question?

Comment: @DonThousand No, but my was only an interaction.

Comment: The OP should mention what "tools" are allowed to solve this problem.

Answer (score 4):

The standard form of equation for lines is
\begin{equation}
ax + by + c = 0,
\end{equation}
if you are talking about a 2D case.
The vector $\left(a,b\right)$ is the normal of the line. In your case, the normal for the first equation is $(1,0)$ while the normal for the latter is $\left(2,2\right)$. The dot product between the two normal vectors is
\begin{equation}
\left(1,0\right) \cdot \left(2,2\right) = 2.
\end{equation}
Also, we know that
\begin{equation}
a \cdot b = \lvert a\rvert \lvert b\rvert \cos{\theta},
\end{equation}
where $\theta$ is the angle between the two vectors. In your case, we have
\begin{equation}
2 = 1\cdot 2\sqrt{2} \cdot \cos{\theta},
\end{equation}
and this leads to
\begin{equation}
\cos{\theta} = \frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}.
\end{equation}
Thus, we have $\theta = 45^{\circ}$

Comment: Approved! But I think that the user he is a student of an high school.

Comment: I am absolutely agree with you. Generally I have studied your answer when I was to the University and actually I and some rare prof. explain that if $r\colon ax+by+c=0$ the vector $\mathbf v=(a,b)\perp r$. I had upvoted before. :-)

Comment: Then that is a little tricky. I guess he should construct a triangle and prove that it is a 90-45-45 triangle through calculating the lengths of sides. Ehmm, but the second equation is a straight line, so that should simplify the problem. He would only need to calculate the angle of the first line with the x-axis or y-axis. This is only a slope then. This is much easier.

Answer (score 0):

A more fundamental/visual approach to solving this problem is as follows:

1. Recognize that there will be a point of intersection between the two lines. We know this must occur at $(x,y)=(5,\frac{3}{2})$, as concluded via substitution:

$$x = 5$$
$$\Rightarrow 2(5) + 2y - 7 = 2y + 3 = 0 $$
$$\Rightarrow y = -\frac{3}{2} $$

2. Now, we need side lengths of a triangle in order to calculate the angle we desire. We know that the $y$-component will be from the line $x-5=0$. In other words, $3/2$ is the length of the triangle's vertical.
3. What about the horizontal? If we take $x=5$, then our angle measurement would be towards the origin. However, we want our angle to be towards the line described by $2x+2y-7=0$. To do this, we need to know this line's intersection with the x-axis, which (by substituting $y=0$) must be at: $$(x,y)=(\frac{7}{2},0)$$ The final $x$-component/horizontal is thus: $$\Delta x=5-\frac{7}{2}=\frac{3}{2}$$ [To help you understand why, I graphed this on Desmos. In this image, the purple line represents the point of 1intersection. If you don't calculate $\Delta x$ and use $x=5$, you can see that you'll get the wrong angle.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/EQQBJ.png)

Since the horizontal and vertical are both $3/2$, and we have a right-angle triangle since we're working off the axes, we conclude the angle measured from $x=5$ to $2x+2y-7=0$ must be $45^\circ$, or: $$\theta=atan(\frac{3/2}{3/2})=atan(1)=45^\circ$$

Comment: You are completely right on this, but, $y=-\frac{3}{2}$ because $2(5)-7=\mathbf{+}3.$ You wrote $-3$; luckily that doesn't really matter for this problem because you can shift the problem to $y=\frac{3}{2}.$

Comment: You're right - I'll edit my answer. Thank you for the feedback.

Answer (score 0):

Here's a way without trig or vectors.

We can find the intersection of the two lines. $x-5=0$ means that $x=5$, so plugging that into the second equation gets us $y=-\frac{3}{2}$. So the point of intersection is $$(5, -\frac{3}{2}).$$

Refer to the Desmos graph [here](https://www.desmos.com/calculator/udty7yr0al). (When solving individually you should always draw out the problem.) The red line is $2x+2y-7=0$ and the blue line is $x-5=0.$ The intersection point $(5, -\frac{3}{2})$ is marked as $X$.

Let's try drawing a line perpendicular to $x-5=0$. We can make it stop when it touches $2x+2y-7=0$. The inspiration for this is because we can try creating a right angle with $x-5=0$, a strictly vertical line. This can give us a right triangle, which is usually helpful on geometry problems. The line is the purple dashed one. It intersects the red line at $A$ and the blue line at $B$.

We now have a right triangle, and it looks to be isosceles, too! More specifically, it seems that $AB =BX$. (Can you prove this? Hint: $A$ has to be the same distance from $B$ as $X$ is.)

Now, a right isosceles triangle has angles of $45-45-90.$ Since we already have the $90^\circ$ angle, our answer must be $$\boxed{45^\circ.}$$

**Note:** *We got lucky that the triangle is a right isosceles. If you don't know trigonometry already, I strongly advise you to learn the basics to solve problems like these in less than a minute. The purple line we drew would also help if we solved using trig functions.*

Answer (score 0):

The angle $\theta$ between any two lines is related to their slopes as follows, $tan\theta=|\frac{m_1-m_2}{1+m_1m_2}|$, where the slope $m$ can be calculated as $m=\frac{-a}{b}$, where $a$ is the coefficient of $x$ and $b$ is the coefficient of $y$. Now in this case, $m_1=\frac{1}{0}$ (I know $\frac{1}{0}$ is undefined, but then it works. I appreciate any comments as to why it works. I think it has to do with limits.) and $m_2=-1$. Putting these values in the equation, we get $tan\theta=|\frac{\frac{1}{0}+1}{1+\frac{-1}{0}}|$, or $tan\theta=|-1|=1$, hence $\theta=45^\circ$.